# Error after buillding React Native on version 0.70

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-reanimated

Error description

[image]

After the App builds successfully, I got this error at my Metro while trying to install the app.

My react-native version is 0.70.

This the error:
**Error: Exception in HostFunction: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libreanimated.so" not found**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is coming because of `react-native-reanimated` library either remove the library or

Use latest version

And

Go to root folder

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean
```

or check this

https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/pull/3551/commits/25defa25d22a50dc068ac720ac4f3d7bde76aa17

Comment: Thanks for your response, but have tried both options and the error persists.

Comment: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/pull/3551/commits/25defa25d22a50dc068ac720ac4f3d7bde76aa17

Comment: This piece of code of your answer goes on  android/build.gradle or goes on node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/build.gradle ?

Comment: Here : node_modules/react-native-reanimated/android/build.gradle

Comment: At least I found a solution that worked i changed the version of this libraries:     "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.3.2",      "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.4",   "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",

Comment: I mentioned above Update version. I am glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen for other reasons as well. For me, it happened because in the
android\gradle.properties file I did not enable the Architecture that I was trying to deploy to:

```
reactNativeArchitectures=armeabi-v7a,arm64-v8a,x86,x86_64
```

Make sure, the Emulator Arch or if you are using a physical device then that Arch is enabled in the above line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't add the proguard rules inside the android app folder and follow the instructions they had given on the website

https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation

Moreover, if you are using the react native version 0.68 & docs say to install the library which react native reanimated@next but it produces an error (merging error with the Hermes) until now there is no stable version of the reanimated library for the react native v0.70. Installing the lower version(stable version) is a better move than doing with the latest version